# opa : stringmap compilation error and HttpRequest.Generic.get_form_data(HttpRequest.request x)

Tags: compilation, opa

I'm trying to compile the following code, but it falis :

```
import stdlib.core.map

function f()
{
        stringmap(string) myM = StringMap.add("rabbit", "horse", StringMap_empty)
        string rabbit= myM["rabbit"]
}
```

Why is that ? I have the feelling that this code was working with my previous release of opa (0.9.*).

How can I access to data stored in a StringMap ? In my code, I want to access the data return by a

```
HttpRequest.Generic.get_form_data(HttpRequest.request x).
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No your code can't have worked on any previous version of Opa. We already discuss about some aspects of Opa and StringMap in a previous thread you opened here: [Opa : howo to manipulate stringmap (and other map)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586367/opa-howo-to-manipulate-stringmap-and-other-map)

In summary:

- Opa is a functional programming language, your function `f` can't end with a binding like `rabbit = v`.
- there is not `myM["rabbit"]` syntax, you have to use `StringMap.get` in your case.

Here is a working code:

```
import stdlib.core.map

function f()
{
        stringmap(string) myM = StringMap.add("rabbit", "horse", StringMap_empty)
        match (StringMap.get("rabbit", myM)) {
        case {none}: "not found"
        case {some:value}: value
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've searched for such a get function in the api, but I've not found it.